# Is using htmlspecialchars() sufficient in all situations?

Tags: php, security, htmlspecialchars

My users are allowed to insert anything into my database.

So using a whitelist / blacklist of characters is not an option.

I'm not worried (covered it) about the database end (SQL injection), but rather code injection in my pages.

Are there any situations where `htmlspecialchars()` wouldn't be sufficient to prevent code injection?

Comment: So, are they allowed to enter anything or disallowed to enter at least angle brackets?

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel: Anything is allowed.

Comment: @downvoter: why the downvote? dupe somewhere? tell me please.

Comment: if anything is allowed, you don't have to replace angle brackets. Make your mind at last.

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel: Now why would you say that??? Anything is allowed as input doesn't mean anything should get 'executed' when displayed... E.g. when a user signs up he can use `<script>alert('test')</script>` as a username, but I don't want that javascript to get executed when another user visits his profile.

Comment: so, javascript is not allowed. You are contradict with yourself :)

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel: since you fail to read: Col. you're right! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Plain `htmlspecialchars` is not sufficient when inserting user text into single quoted attributes. You need to add `ENT_QUOTES` in that case and you need to pass the encoding.

```
<tag attr='<?php echo htmlspecialchars($usertext);?>'> //dangerous if ENT_QUOTES is not used
```

When inserting user text into javascript/json as string you'll need additional escaping.

I think it fails for stange character sets too. But if you use one of the usual charsets UTF-8, Latin1,... it will work as expected.

Comment: I hate single quoted attributes :) Thanks for the heads up on the JS part since it will be the case in some point in the future.

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not sufficient in all situations. It highly depends on your codebase. For example, if you use JavaScript to make certain AJAX requests to a database, `htmlspecialchars()` will sometimes not be enough (depending where you use it). If you want to protect cookies from JavaScript XSS, `htmlspecialchars()` will also not be good enough.

Here are some examples of when `htmlspecialchars()` may fail: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Interpreter_Injection#Why_htmlspecialchars_is_not_always_enough. Your question is also highly dependent on what database you're using (not everyone uses MySQL). If you're writing a complex applicaton I highly suggest using one of the many frameworks out there that abstract these annoying little idiosyncrasies and let you worry about the application code.

Comment: Why is the database relevant? DB access and encoding output are separate concerns.

Comment: As far as Postgres is concerned it doesn't matter (they both use SQL) - but some databases don't use SQL.

Answer (score 2):

Using `htmlspecialchars` is sufficient when inserting inside HTML code. The way it encodes the characters makes it impossible for the resulting text to *“break out”* of the current element. That way it can neither create other elements, nor script segments etc.

However in all other situations, `htmlspecialchars` it not automatically enough. For example when you use it to insert code within some JavaScript area, for example when you fill a JavaScript string with it, you will need additional methods to make it safe. In that case `addslashes` could help.

So depending on where you insert the resulting text, `htmlspecialchars` gives you either enough security or not. As the function name already suggests, it just promises security for HTML.

Answer (score 1):

htmlspecialchars will suffice. With `<` and `>` being converted to `&lt;` and `&gt;` you cannot include scripts anymore.

Comment: Depends on where the user text is inserted into the html. If it's outside a tag/script it will be enough.

Comment: True, forgot to mention that. If you don't want the content to be interpreted as a script, you should not include it in script tags.

Comment: Not true for attribute values.